# Unable to open an existing PowerPoint Presentation (2016) from Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have tried to use a code snippet from a previous question on Stack Overflow just starting with opening an existing PowerPoint file from Excel using VBA. The example code snippet will not work for me.

I am using Excel 2016, and the reference object mode is Microsoft Object Model 16 Library, not the Model 12 referred to earlier. Maybe this is the source of the problem. The procedure I wrote, modified from this site was

```
Public Sub OpenPPT()
    Dim DestinationPPT As String
    Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation

    'Easier to define manually set links up front so it's easier to change/modify
    DestinationPPT = "D:\Downloads\Automate_Excel\IR_Seeker_UpdateRevA.pptx"
    Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT)
End Sub
```

The routine gags on the `Set myPresentation` line

Comment: What does the Error Message say?  That will greatly reduce the amount of guesswork involved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this line, so that you open the PowerPoint Application, *before* you try to open the Presentation in it:

```
Set PowerPointApp = New PowerPoint.Application
```

As an analogy: you need to make sure that you are looking at a building before you try to open the door...

Answer (score -1):

You should change

```
Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT)
```

To

```
Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.myPresentation.Open(DestinationPPT)
```

I would also add "Option explicit" outside of all the subs so it will yell at you if you have a undefined variable as well as correct some variable typos.

Comment: The `Presentations` collection is part of the `PowerPoint.Application` object, in the same way that `Workbooks` is part of the `Excel.Applications` object.  `myPresentation`, on the other hand, is not part of `PowerPoint.Application`...